# How to make an icon next to email address

Tags: email, icons

This is screenshot from mail.ru. Next to Apple Store there is Apple icon. Same for Twitter and for Netflix.

we searched the email headers, but found anything. How is this done?

We can see similar icons in Gmail, but until recently I thought it is something related to Gmail only.

---

[image]

---

### full headers here:

```
headers were removed as I found they are not relevant...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and testing, I found they use `gravatar` at https://gravatar.com/ .